# Can I use an oozie action as a template that I call many times?

Tags: oozie, directed-acyclic-graphs, oozie-workflow

I have a shell oozie action that takes in a number of arguments that get passed to the shell script. I want to trigger that action multiple times with different arguments each time. An example dag would look something like:

```
    Start
   /  |  \
f(a) f(d) f(g)
 |    |    |
 V    V    V
f(b) f(e) f(h)
 |    |    |
 V    V    V
f(c) f(f) f(i)
   \  |  /
     End
```

Is it possible to achieve this without having a bunch of duplicate actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible with `Oozie sub-workflow` option.

Compose the Shell action as a sub-workflow and call the sub-workflow from many places from the main workflow with different input values.

```
    <action name="call_sub_workflow_1">
      <sub-workflow>
          <app-path>${workflowAppUri}/sub_workflow_with_shell_action/</app-path>
          <propagate-configuration/>
          <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>argument_1</name>
                  <value>${wf:actionData('previous_action')['val1']}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>argument_2</name>
                  <value>${val2}</value>
              </property>
          </configuration>
      </sub-workflow>
      <ok to="End"/>
      <error to="Fail"/>
    </action>
```

Main workflow with sub-workflow directory structure will looks like,

```
   main_workflow_dir
   |
   |--job.properties
   |
   |--workflow.xml  # main workflow, can call sub workflow from multiple places
   |
   |--sub_workflow_with_shell_action
       |
       |--shell script
       |
       |--workflow.xml  # sub workflow contains the shell script action and takes arguments
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. One question though, does the 'template' workflow need to be set up in any special way or can I just directly call a normal workflow as a sub-workflow?

Comment: @JaredDuPont, I updated the answer for Workflow directory structure with subworkflow.

Comment: Does the sub-workflow have to be in a sub-directory and does it have to be called "workflow.xml"? I ask because it does not look like you specified a workflow name in the code you showed, so I assume it automatically picks up 'workflow.xml'

Comment: yes, sub workflow should be in sub directory, this sub directory has to be configured in <app-path> property while calling sub workflow as shown in the above code. This sub workflow's directory should contain a workflow.xml file.

Comment: Refer this [repository](https://github.com/airawat/OozieSamples/tree/master/oozieProject/workflowWithSubworkflow) for a sub workflow example.

Comment: Is it possible for the subworkflow.xml file to be present in any other directory other than within the same directory as parent workflow.xml